# Eclipse Output Folder Not Working

Tags: eclipse

I have changed project build path to my webcontent folder, but it doesn't generate the class file to my new folder, still generate the class file to /target/classes.

I have checked the "Allow output folders for source folders", and give the default and output folder to webcontent folder. Eclipse still build to the older folder. Even restart.

Eclipse version is
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

With M2E Installed

Comment: Changed the build include pattern to All, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you have changed "Default Output folder" in

```
project->properties->java Build path ->default output folder
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the build include pattern to All, then everything works fine.